# Сервис для приватного стриминга

Tags: веб-служба

Добрый вечер. Нужен сервис для стриминга вебинаров на сайте. Задача в том, чтобы стриминги были приватными и доступ к ним был только у пользователей, зарегистрированных и авторизованных на сайте (ютуб не подходит, потому что можно отправить ссылку на сам стрим). Идеальным был бы вариант с доступом по токенам, генерирумым на сайте. Возможно, есть какое-то облачное решение. Спасибо

Comment: Облачное решение есть. Azure Streaming Services. Когда до компа доберусь, попытаюсь расписать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания сайта с вебинарами, вы можете воспользоваться [Azure Streaming Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/services/media-services/). При помощи данной технологии была реализованна трансляция зимних Олимпийских игр в Сочи 2014. Данный сервис включает в себя несколько подтипов услуг. Для решения вашей задачи можно воспользоваться службой "Видео в реальном времени" (Live Video). Если вы решите воспользоваться данной службой, то можете не переживать о таких деталях как пропускная способность и прочее. Есть лишь один большой минус - это [относительно высокая стоимость](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/). На данный момент это от 62руб/час при условии, что стрим будет передоваться лишь в одном битрейте. За стримы с Live Encoding придется платить около 1200р за час. (Цены указанны на 30.03.2016).

В общем всё что вам надо будет сделать это реализовать на вашем сайте систему аутентификации пользователей и распределения прав на просмотр вебинаров. Ну и плюс такие обычно присутствующие вещи как чат, скачка документов итд, но это не так сложно. 
Если вы пользуютесь не .NET технологиями, то можно воспользоваться REST API от Azure для данного сервиса. [Ссылка на документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn783458.aspx). Ну а если всё таки .NET, то [жизнь с SDK будете ещё проще](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-creating-live-encoder-enabled-channel/).

P.S. Можете глянуть в сторону Amazon Elastic Transcoder. [Вот статья - сравнение](https://habrahabr.ru/company/epam_systems/blog/210446/). Но она сравнивает не Live Streaming, a Offline, так что на сравнение цен смотреть бесполезно. Ну и плюс я не понял на скорую руку, вообще есть ли в AWS Live Video...

Comment: AWS Elemental Live?